# Retrieving messages from the twitter connecter resultes into 403

Tags: unificationengine

I have successfully registered the twitter connector with my app and created a user. I'm able to send tweets and the `test` and `info` apis both work. Only when I try to retrieve messages the connector returns the following result:

```
{"Status":{"twitter":{"status":417,"info":"417 Connector returned error: 403 Forbidden"}},"messages":{"twitter":null}}
```

I send the request to `/v2/message/retrieve` with the following json body:

```
{"uri": "unified://twitter"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my twitter app didn't have DM permissions. I just saw `Read & write` and thought that would be enough.

If someone has the same problem, go to your [app settings](https://apps.twitter.com/), change the permissions and regenerate your personal access token.

Comment: I am facing problem sending messages to Facebook connector. I am getting 403 error. I am using php curl.

Answer (score 0):

curl -XPOST https://apiv2.unificationengine.com/v2/message/retrieve -u USER_ACCESSKEY:USER_ACCESSSECRET --data "{\"uri\":\"unified://UNIQUE_CONNECTION_IDENTIFIER\"}" -k

Can you please check if the above command works for you? The 403 error is returned by twitter (https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes).

Comment: The command you posted returns the same response as in my question.