# Retrieving messages from facebook connector results into 404

Tags: unificationengine

After the [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39233431/retrieving-messages-from-the-twitter-connecter-resultes-into-403/39242655#39242655) with the twitter connector I tried facebook and also have some problems:

```
{
  "Status": {
    "facebook": {
      "status": 417,
      "info": "417 Connector returned error: 404 Not Found"
    }

  },
  "messages": {
    "facebook": null
  }
}
```

Again every other api call works but the connector returns an error from the facebook api when I try to retrieve messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation the current facebook connector dosen't have receiving capability. Only twitter DM and whatsapp have receiving capability.